# not getting data when using SWR and context API in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, use-context, swr

am trying to see the data am that am get from an API using SWR and also setting the currency in the API to what ever the user is using through context API but i can't see any data. please can someone help out. to know what am not doing right.

here is the code

```
import React from 'react'
import useSWR from "swr";
import {CryptoState} from "../context/cryptoContext"
import { useContext } from "react";


function Trending() {

  const {currency } = useContext(CryptoState)

  const address = `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=${currency}&order=gecko_desc&per_page=10&page=1&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=24h`;
  const fetcher = async (url) => await axios.get(url).then((res) => res.data);
  const { data, error } = useSWR(address, fetcher);

  if (error) <p>Loading failed...</p>;
  if (!data) <h1>Loading...</h1>;

  return (
    <div>
      {data && console.log(data)}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Trending;
```

Comment: can you console.log(currency)?

Comment: yes. is showing

Comment: Maybe try making the `Trending()`  function `async`

Comment: still not working

Comment: `async (url) => await ` should not be necessary, also use return for loading and error state

Answer (score 0):

**Code below works (tested):**

```
import React from 'react'
import useSWR from "swr";


function Trending() {


  const address = `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=USD&order=gecko_desc&per_page=10&page=1&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=24h`;
  const { data, error } = useSWR(address);

  if (error) <p>Loading failed...</p>;
  if (!data) <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  return (
    <div>
      <pre>
        <code>
          {JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}
        </code>
      </pre>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Trending;
```

Check your `const {currency } = useContext(CryptoState)`

In your case `fetcher` is not needed, `fetcher` variable is made for complex cases.

P.S. Instead of checking your currency and using `useContext` hook you can send this variable to your function directly as `function Trending(currency)`

Comment: i just tried it, but am getting undefined. please could be the problem

Comment: As I told you - send your value of `currency` to your component directly. `function Trending(currency) { //function body }` OR SHARE code of `"../context/cryptoContext"`